# how to make the field label in Views hidden or visible?

Tags: views

i have a view page with Table format i want to control the label of the fields that i added befor .
i changed the php code in (views-view-table.tpl.php) befor so now i can't control the field label ( hidden / visible ) from the view 
this is the code that i have now :

[image]

and this is the view page even i check the label nothing happen!

[image]

anyone can help me with this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 1 week searching i found the solution :
simply by adding this code :

```
<?php print $header['$field_name']; ?>
```

this code will print the label of your field.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal because you are using a template file, view's will use your template file and nothing from the UI (User Interface) for fields.

Therefore, you will need to type `Address:` in your template file, just like you did for `Location:`, on line 47.

Comment: and what if i have two languages ? (arbaic - english ) 
how can i solve it ?

Comment: @WaseeemAlfarra : nowhere in your question I see any indication that it is about multiple languages. Therefor I think the question in your previous comment should be posted as a new question (if you want add a link to this question as a kind of followup question).